# Can't recover the name of the menuitem clicked in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, menuitem, routedeventargs

I'm trying to recover the name of the menuitem where I clicked and I it always returns an empty string:

```
    private void MenuP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menu4 = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
        string ss = menu4.Name;         /// always empty. why?             
    }
```

The XAML:

```
Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MenuItem.Click" Handler="MenuP_Click"></EventSetter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CatStyle">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding XPath=submenu}"/>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.DisplayMemberPath" Value="@es"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/> <ColumnDefinition Width="677*"/> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Name="MenuP" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource datos}, XPath=//menues/Menux}" DisplayMemberPath="@es" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CatStyle}">

 </Grid>
```

the menuitems.count is always 0 too.
How can I know which menuItem was clicked by the user?

Comment: Step through and see what type e.OriginalSource actually is. I think you might not be casting the right thing to MenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get clicked `MenuItem` from `sender` parameter instead, and do type-casting as follow :

```
MenuItem menu4 = (MenuItem)sender;
string ss = menu4.Name;
```

This way of casting will throw exception if you cast wrong object instead of returning `null` like it's counterpart (`... As MenuItem`). That will make it clear in case you have wrong type-casting problem.

**UPDATE :**

I think you got empty string in `ss` because you never set `Name` property of `MenuItem`, at least I can't see that in the code posted. If you want to get string displayed in the `MenuItem` you can try this way instead :

```
MenuItem menu4 = (MenuItem)sender;
var xml = (XmlElement)menu4.DataContext;
var es = xml.Attribute["es"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It´s the same result. Its not null. when I move the mouse over the menu4 it reports: {System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem Header:System.Xml.XmlElement Items.Count:0}

Comment: @user2367101 updated my answer. I can't see where you set `Name` property, so I guess you want sth else : text displayed in `MenuItem` maybe?

Comment: Yes I want that text or something to identify the item clicked. Anything. Im using a XML file. I have this code :     
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="datos" Source="Menues2.xml"/>
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: About the update: I tried to set the name property with a Setter in the itemstyle:
        <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Name" Value="abc"></Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="MenuItem.Click" Handler="MenuP_Click"></EventSetter>
        </Style>
and it dont let me compile. It reports 2 errors:
Error 2 Must have non-null value for 'Setter.Property'. 
Error 1 'Name' property cannot be set in the current element's Style.

Comment: how about the 2nd code snippet, does it work to get displayed text (value of `es` attribute of corresponding xml element)?